# angular-ui-notification and translate message

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

in my app i use angular-translate for translate my app. Now i start using angular-ui-notification, and I'm stuck. Angular translate does not work when trying to translate messages from the angular-ui-notification.
Angular-translate use this syntax for translate in view

```
{{ badRequestServerError | translate}}
```

And here is in my controller for notification

```
if (response.status == 400) {
    Notification.error({message: '{{ badRequestServerError | translate}}', positionY: 'bottom', positionX: 'right'});
         };
```

But this not working. When open i browser i allways get this

> {{ badRequestServerError | translate}}

in view I try to use without quotation marks, but still nothing. 
On [github angular-ui-notification](https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification/issues) I can not find anything where is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$scope.badRequestServerError` value is the the translation key, you can inject `$filter` into your controller and then:

```
Notification.error({message: $filter('translate')($scope.badRequestServerError), positionY: 'bottom', positionX: 'right'});
```

Or if you're using the status code of the server response and `badRequestServerError` is already the translation key, you can just set it this way:

```
Notification.error({message: $filter('translate')('badRequestServerError'), positionY: 'bottom', positionX: 'right'});
```

Comment: Nice solution, but how to define translated text in my translate.js file in this case. Example, i have english and i add badRequestServerError: "bad reguest etc.", and for croatian i add badRequestServerError: "kriv zahtjev". How to handle with this, how to on change language set on "$scope" message for selected language?

Comment: If you're using `angular-translate`, it will not translate the text by itself. You should have defined a pair of key values first. For example: `{'BAD_REQUEST_ENG': 'Bad request', 'BAD_REQUEST_CRO': 'kriv zahtjev'}`, and make your server send just the keys. Check out the "How it works" section of `angular-translate` [site](https://angular-translate.github.io/).

Comment: thnx, i defined this, and this working (i have little problem with english)...i give you on plunker not working version, because my app have many many parts... here is link for translate.js file and for my controller https://plnkr.co/edit/4ITHsiDCtie1I1c5noHI?p=catalogue  thanke you

Comment: Thanke you thanke you.... I can't give you "+1" because I'm new to the forum and system does not allow adding "+1" for new users.

Comment: No problem, glad the answer helped :)